# WCF set bindings on service at runtime

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

My app has to be installed on my client's webservers.  Some clients want to use SSL and some do not.  My app has a WCF service and I currently have to go into the web.config for each install and switch the security mode from `<security mode="Transport">` to `<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">` depending on the client's SSL situation.  I am able to set the client bindings at runtime.  However, I would like to know if there is a way to set the service bindings at runtime(on the server side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely! It depends on how you're hosting your WCF services. Saying it has to be installed on the webservers, I would assume you're hosting in IIS.

In that case, you need to create your own descendant of `ServiceHostFactory` - which really isn't that big a deal.

Your `CustomServiceHostFactory` is needed to return an instance of your `ServiceHost`, properly configured to your needs, to IIS.

In the `CreateServiceHost` method of the custom factory, you basically set up your `ServiceHost` and configure all its endpoints, behaviors, bindings, etc. - all in code, all under your full control. You can do whatever you need to do here, to configure your service just as needed.

In order to host your service. You'll need to adapt the `MyService.svc` file to include that `CustomServiceHostFactory` as the factory to use:

```
<% @ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="YourService" 
                 Factory="CustomServiceHostFactory" %>
```

and that's it!

Check out [Extending Hosting Using ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702697.aspx) on MSDN for more details, and see the [A Custom ServiceHostFactory](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFServiceHostFactory.aspx) article on CodeProject for a sample.